# How do I add transparent color to my dropdown button in Tailwind CSS flowbite in my nextjs project?

Tags: next.js, drop-down-menu, tailwind-css

I added a dropdown in my Header using flow bite in nextjs, but the color of the dropdown is fixed i.e. blue. I tried using adding a custom color to that button using

```
className='dark:bg-transparent bg-transparent'
```

in my Dropdown but still, the problem persists

Here is my code[image]

if I add the same className in my Dropdown tag then the whole dropdown becomes transparent, I just want the button of the dropdown to be transparent.
**No external CSS file must be included

Is there any particular CSS for flowbite Dropdown in NextJS?

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom CSS for this, so by creating a class for transparent backgrounds and adding it to the navbar, it should override the current styling.

You can see [this issue](https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite-react/issues/442) for more information and possible solutions.